# How to Identify existing MTA on my Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, mail, nagios3, mta

I am a beginner for Ubuntu Server and have very little knowledge about it.

We have a running instance of Nagios Core from a production server **TEST-1 (Ubuntu 14.04.2)**. It was set up before i joined the organization so i am unaware of existing MTA configuration. We are properly receiving email notifications from this server.

Now i am trying to set up a 2nd instance of Nagios Core on a different production server **TEST-2 (Ubuntu 14.04.2)**. I am facing issues setting up MTA.

**I want to check the existing configuration of MTA on TEST-1 so i can apply the same on TEST-2.** Can anyone please help me to check it step-by-step?

Comment: You know what MTA is used or not.

Answer (score 3):

Usually MTA identifies itself in SMTP greeting message.

You may use `telnet 127.0.0.1 25` to get SMTP greeting message.

Other steps are MTA type dependent (exim/postfix/sendmail).

Comment: Telnet is usually not enabled

Comment: Using `telnet` client program does not require enabling local `telnet` service/daemon.  `telnet` client program is frequently used to "hand debug" human readable protocols like SMTP.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right :\ +1 great idea.

Comment: I reconfigured postfix on the new server. To test i tried sending mail to my organization domain it failed but test mail goes to gmail-id with no issues?

Below is the log dump:

Sep  4 12:32:14 ip-172-30-1-13 postfix/local[4754]: 189E0808F7: to=<sushantk@mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.09, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "sushantk")

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this post and still looking for answers, I asked this question for my Ubuntu 16.04 system.  There are only a few common ones (especially if you're only asking about default MTAs).  You can find the common ones with a [google search](https://www.google.cl/search?q=list%20of%20common%20linux%20mtas&oq=list%20of%20common%20linux%20mtas&aqs=chrome..69i57.6488j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or [list of MTAs like this page](https://www.tecmint.com/best-mail-transfer-agents-mta-for-linux/).

Then, knowing what they are, you can look for their running binaries.  If you do a `ps -ef`, you'll find (as I did, and if you're running 16.04), that postfix, one of the common MTAs is listed numerous times.  So that's your default.  You can google to find out what the binary name is for the other MTAs.

I know this isn't the most elegant solution, but I haven't found an elegant solution as I've searched, so this solution at least got the job done for me.  Hope it saves someone else some time...